# create list from parsed web page in python

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I'm a little new to web parsing in python. I am using beautiful soup. I would like to create a list by parsing strings from a webpage. I've looked around and can't seem to find the right answer. Doe anyone know how to create a list of strings from a web page? Any help is appreciated.

My code is something like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url="http://www.any_url.com"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

#The data I need is coming from HTML tag of td
page_find=soup.findAll('td')

for page_data in page_find:

   print page_data.string

#I tried to create my list here
page_List = [page_data.string]
print page_List
```

Comment: Your indents didn't come through properly. can you [edit] your question to fix them?

Comment: @mhlester Were you talking about my for loop? I just edited.

Comment: i was, thank you. But the for loop itself is indented further than it should be?

Comment: @mhlester Ok, fixed it. Sorry about the indents.

Comment: what are you trying to do? get all the `page_data.string` values into the `page_List`?

Comment: @isedev Yes. There's a lot of data from the page I want under a 'td' tag. I want to take the contents of that table and make a list out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having difficulty understanding what you are trying to achieve... If you want all values of `page_data.string` in `page_List`, then your code should look like this:

```
page_List = []
for page_data in page_find:
    page_List.append(page_data.string)
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
page_List = [page_data.string for page_data in page_find]
```

The problem with your original code is that you create the list using the text from the last `td` element only (i.e. outside of the loop which processes each `td` element).

Comment: Sorry about not being too clear. This appears to work. I'll work with this for a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is modified to call the web page as a string

```
import requests
the_web_page_as_a_string = requests.get(some_path).content

from lxml import html
myTree = html.fromstring(the_web_page_as_a_string)
td_list = [ e for e in myTree.iter() if e.tag == 'td']


text_list = []
for td_e in td_list:
   text = td_e.text_content()
   text_list.append(text)
```

Comment: `tdtext_list = [ e.text_content() for e in myTree.iter() if e.tag == 'td']` ?

Comment: Yes that is faster and more efficient but I always prefer to spell it out so a novice can play with each of the parts and understand it and I was trying to decide if their needed to be some error handling if there is no text_content for one or more elements

Comment: @PyNEwbi That's right I'm a little bit of a novice. Can you show where a url gets called in that statement? I haven't used lxml before.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend lxml over BeautifulSoup, when you start scraping alot of pages the speed advantage of lxml is hard to ignore.

```
import requests
import lxml.html

dom = lxml.html.fromstring(requests.get('http://www.any_url.com').content)
page_list = [x for x in dom.xpath('//td/text()')]
print page_list
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'll make a note even though I've already accepted the solution above.